# Align video element with background image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align a YouTube video inside this background image:

[like this image on tiny pic](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2aijw3o.jpg)

[This is what i tried jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yogiji/wcz1ms8a/)

```
 <div class="video-bar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<style>
        .video-bar {
        background: url(images/slice/video-image.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 453px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Well, your CSS is not contained within a <style> tag.  But absolute or relative positioning is what you will need to do.  Or use your image as a background.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change quite a few things to make this work, so I won't list them all. A primary one was that `background-size: cover` doesn't work if you're using the shorthand `background` property.

```
.video-bar {
    background-image: url(http://oi60.tinypic.com/294rtyu.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 34% top;
}
.video-wrapper {
    margin-top: 22%;
    padding: 60px 40px;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row video-bar">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-wrapper">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wcz1ms8a/3/)**

Adjust padding and background position to suit. It would simplify things if the background image's video box was centered.

Comment: hi thanks for your effort please have a look on this image http://oi57.tinypic.com/2aijw3o.jpg

Comment: To achieve that you'd need a whole different approach. You'd have to overlay a partially transparent graphic on top of the video, which would disallow user interaction with the controls. You'd then have to program separate controls in another area of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Your iframe should not be inside of the div layer that has the image "overlay".  Because then it's embedded inside the overlay instead of placing the overlay "over" the iframe.

I think what you are looking for is more like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tcg2nyLd/

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.video-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://oi60.tinypic.com/294rtyu.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 453px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.video-bar .container-fluid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.video-wrapper {
    height: 350px !important;
    left: calc(50% - 395px);
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 550px;
}

.video-wrapper iframe {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you see i am not able to control the video inside the frame. this is what i am actually looking for how can i control it.

Comment: I actually just updated the code a little for better display.  But what do you mean you are looking to control the video inside the frame?  Do you just mean show the controls?  If so, just see my update.  You can adjust the height and margin as needed.

Comment: Have you tried scaling the Fiddle panel? Your example only works at one size. It's not responsive.

Comment: @James yes i am trying to control video inside frame play and pause which im not able to do

Comment: @Yogiji I see.  You will probably need to use YouTube's API and create your own buttons for the functions.

Comment: @Yogiji I've updated my answer (code and fiddle link).  It is responsive with the container.  Also fits a lot better.  However, you will still need to use the YouTube API to create your own controls.

Comment: @James thank you for your efforts i am implementing the same using youtube api i will update as i am done